# datepicker doesn't save selected date

Tags: android, datepicker, calendar

When you select the day, month and year, always save today's time. this is what i tried

```
private DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener dateSetListener = new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
       public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int año, int mes,
                                 int dia) {
           isDateChanged = true;
       }
   };
private void AgregarCumpleaños() {
       if (isDateChanged = false)
       {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Elija su cumpleaños", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else
       {
           datePicker = findViewById(R.id.cumpleano);
           final Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
           int dia =  ca.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
           int mes = ca.get(Calendar.MONTH);
           int año = ca.get(Calendar.YEAR);

           final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM");
           saveCurrentDate = dateFormatter.format(ca.getTime());
```

I need to save the selected month and day or save it in its variables

Comment: I think you just gotta study a couple of similar examples a little more closely and learn the correct way to do this. You may also consider throwing away the long outmoded and poorly designed `Calendar` class and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any implement for `OnDateChangedListener`

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        datePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Log.d("Date", "Year=" + year + " Month=" + (month + 1) + " day=" + dayOfMonth);

                }
            });
```

Comment: oh, my bad i forget to paste  that implement,  i  gonna edit,
but I'm looking at the code in a different way